# Will a dead fan header cause computer to not POST?

Tags: boot, motherboard, fan

I just added 2 new fans and 1 RGB strip to my rig.
I tried booting it with just power cord plugged in and it booted without any problem.
So i turned it off and plugged in my hdmi cable and try booting it again. This time it won't boot, and all the fans are spinning at max speed.

so i tried swapping the fan among the headers, and i found that 1 of the header is not working (the fans will not spin if plugged into that header).

so here comes my question, is my motherboard dead? is it caused by the dead fan header?

here are the troubleshooting that I have done so far:
1. unplug everything extras leaving only cpu, ram, gpu, ssd. result: cpu fan (the only fan left) spinning when i turn on the power
2. reset my cmos. result: same as above
3. unplug cpu and motherboard psu connectors. result: same as above

Comment: It is more likely a symptom than a cause.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams so u are saying that the dead fan header could be a symptom of my motherboard not posting?

Comment: It could be a symptom of motherboard damage.

Comment: Since the first fail to boot was after the adding of the HDMI cable - then perhaps it was that that caused the damage.... Now, the fan(s) failing is only an effect not necessarily the cause...

Comment: @SolarMike please checkout my updated post

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams are the any ways that i can troubleshoot this other than getting another motherboard to test it?

Comment: Sounds like hardware damage

Comment: @Ramhound which hardware are u referring to? because i tried unplugging everything and it still won't post

Comment: The only hardware that has a Power On Self Test.  You do realize the unplugging the cpu power tells us nothing right, of course your system won’t POST if you do that.

Comment: so the conclusion should be a dead motherboard right?

Comment: @TommyLee you updated your post, but my comment still stands - ie connecting the hdmi cable caused the damage....

Comment: @SolarMike but i really highly doubt the hdmi cable caused the damage as my graphics card is still working fine... furthermore the hdmi was working fine previously